# Realm for Cassandra DB to implement container managed security

Tags: java, security, cassandra

I need to create a realm for Cassandra DB (similar to the JDBC realm) to implement container managed security for an application. Can someone point how to do that perhaps by pointing to some samples/examples as I have no idea what's to be there in that realm
?

I am looking to implement container security in my jsf application that uses cassandra database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of your Application Server. Since JBoss and GlassGish are open source you can check how they have implemented the JDBCRealms and take it as base for your own Security Provider based on Cassandra.